# Is there any way to add nameserver without modification of configuration files?

Tags: linux, dns

I need to add my own nameserver, but if I boot installation CD/DVD, I can't edit configuration files. So I'm searching for any way to add the nameserver from terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a name server by editing /etc/resolv.conf as root.

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Add the line

```
nameserver 10.10.10.10
```

Change `10.10.10.10` to the IP address of your nameserver.

Comment: But isn't there any command to change it without editing the resolv.conf?

Comment: Your distribution might have a helper script that updates nameservers but all it would do is edit resolv.conf.  Is there a reason why you can't edit it directly?